# How likely I am to meet my antimatter self?

Tags: antimatter, matter

I read that, when a particle and it's corresponding particle of antimatter meet they annihilate and releases a large amount of energy. I also read that if I met my antimatter self and we Shook hand or touch each other we'd annihilate each other but the question is

**How likely I am to meet my antimatter self on the earth ?**

**Do they exist for everyone ?**

Comment: $\text{Budhathoki}+\overline{\text{Budhathoki}}\to\gamma \gamma$?

Answer (score 4):

You will not meet your antimatter self on earth, nor anywhere else. For all we know, the Universe is made out of matter only. This does not mean that antimatter particles do not exist. They are created in high energy collisions or in photon conversions all the time, but the antimatter particles annihilate again after a short time scale, since they are surrounded by matter particles. This is exactly what you read.

Since every antimatter particle annihilates again after a short time, there is no chance of building up complex structures like an anti human being. Note that in laboratories it has recently been achieved to assemble anti-hydrogen. That is an anti-proton orbited by a positron (an anti-electron).

Why there is such an asymmetry between matter and antimatter in the Universe is one of the big open questions in particle physics and cosmology.

Comment: That's correct. But it might be a follow up question, if an antimatter person might exist in some distant galaxy.